# crowdsale contract on my Ethereum Wallet for windows

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, crowdsale

I first created a token without difficulty with Ethereum Wallet can be see here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x926351469a1a97Ca5AB9b80928a0Ba01493d39F9#readContract.

Now I'm trying to do a crowdsale contract with the code that I have find on this link https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale

But I can't see on the right column of My Ethereum Wallet the "Select contract to deploy" option.

it says `No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
^-----------------------------------------------^,`

I guess I got it wrong, I'm not a developer or coder, but curious to learn.

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong ?

Thanks,

Benj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a warning, not an error. It's informing you that if you don't explicitly state the visibility of a function, it defaults to `public`.

You can get rid of the warning by being explicit:

```
function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public;
```

Comment: I got you ! I still don't have the right column of My Ethereum Wallet the "Select contract to deploy" option.

Insteard I have another warning:

' No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
    function Crowdsale(
    ^
Spanning multiple lines.
, '

Comment: And you can't figure out how to fix that line? It's the exact same warning as the one I gave you a fix for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I never coded anything.

I am really a beginner.

For the story, I lost an artist friend named Benjamin Mecz. Since that day, I wanted to create a token in his name. I do not know yet what it can serve (I have some ideas), but I try to follow the tutorial, to learn. I have no basis in this area. Thanks again

Comment: I understand, better late than never.
I finally have the right column of My Ethereum Wallet with the option "Select contract to deploy".